# Amazon Cognito -> Amazon Quicksight MFA / SSO

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cognito, amazon-quicksight

I am/have been working on a project with my company for a little while. Baseline of the project:

Have a userpool through Amazon Cognito.
AuthN users VIA Cognito with Username / Password
MFA Users with Authentication App(Of your choice) / SMS
SSO from Cognito to AWS Quicksight

With that being said, I am trying to avoid utilizing an EC2 instance.
I am trying to AVOID the requirement of System Administrators for account upkeep.
I want the User to login via Cognito at the HostedUI and automatically redirect to the Dashboards INSIDE of the Quicksight Account that is provided to them. I am the admin to the account so i can create users on both Cognito and Quicksight.
Trying to remain ** serverless **

My problem is:

I AuthN users with MFA via Cognito. Once I AuthN with Cognito, it sends me to the Quicksight login to re-Authenticate via Quicksight Credentials.

To reiterate the problem, I want to BYPASS the re-authentication requirement from Quicksight and just go straight from Cognito AuthN to Quicksight Dashboard.

AuthN = Authenticate
MFA = MultiFactor Authentication

I have created a/an
S3 Static Webpage to act as HostedUI then redirect to Quicksight for credentials check and AuthN from there

Lambda functions to assist with the transfer of credentials, created an Elastic Beanstalk to manage these functions

IAM Policy to ensure users are added for mitigation of unauth users into quicksight

SSO SAML auth through Quicksight and added the Beanstalk / S3 Static URL's

Identity pool for those users under one policy with Implicit Allow

Utilized API Gateway Console to direct Get / Post requests with Quicksight

** I am not able to utilize CloudFront **

### Expectations

User hits endpoint URL (HostedUI)

Logins Username, Password and MFA

User gains access to Quicksight without further AuthN requests / requirements

Comment: I have the exact same questions, you ever find a solution?